# How to use excel vba code to change the color of a series in a box and whisker plot?

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to code anything that will change the colors of a series in a box and whisker plot, and I can't find any hints at all online.

I've tried using/modifying code that changes the color of series in scatterplots, but those don't work for box and whisker plots. I've tried recording a macro, but the code it produces doesn't show anything for the color change, it just shows me selecting the series and then the code ends, completely leaving out the color change, which I've never seen for any other type of plot when I've tried to do this.

This is the code that I used to make the plot:

```
Worksheets("Data Summary").Activate
Range(cells(4, 2), cells(y + 3, a + 1)).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(406, xlBoxwhisker).Select
For seriesNumber = 1 To a
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(seriesNumber).Name = cells(3,   seriesNumber + 1).Value
Next seriesNumber    


Set capacityChart = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
capacityChart.Name = "Data Chart"

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Data Chart").Activate
ActiveChart.SetElement (301)
ActiveChart.SetElement (307)
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "x axis name"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (300)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
Selection.Caption = "y axis name"
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SetElement (348)
ActiveChart.HasLegend = True
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is a couple of months old, but I had the same issue today, and it took a lot to track this down.  (Nothing out there that I could find easily.)

Hopefully this will help you if you still need it:

```
Dim cht As Chart
Dim s As Series

ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Select
Set cht = ActiveChart
Set s = cht.SeriesCollection(1)
s.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = 49407
```

Just a heads up that I found this frequently crashed Excel if I ran it with the VBE open, but with it closed it worked just fine.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Getting good information on how to format box and whiskers charts is tough. Thank you for this answer!